# Javascript, String with '<' or '>'

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to set the inner text of a `div` with Javascript with text including `<` or `>` but it is not working. Any ideas?

Here's my code sample (simple HTML with easy Javascript) with test-click-actions.

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="aaa">
div
</div>

<hr>

<a onclick="getElementById('aaa').innerHTML = 'abc';">click ok1</a>
<p>
<a onclick="var str='asbc'; getElementById('aaa').innerHTML = str;">click ok2</a>
<p>
<a onclick="getElementById('aaa').innerHTML = '<uio>';">click nok1</a>
<p>
<a onclick="getElementById('aaa').innerHTML = '&lt;wer&gt;';">click nok2</a>
<p>
<a onclick="var str='<abc>'; getElementById('aaa').innerHTML = str;">click nok3</a>
<p>
<a onclick="var str='&lt;abc&gt;'; getElementById('aaa').innerHTML = str;">cl nok4</a>
<p>
<a onclick="alert ('&lt;wer&gt;');">click a</a>
<p>
<a onclick="alert ('<w34r>');">click b</a>
<p>

</body>
</html>
```

It's working in the alerts, but not in setting the `innerHTML`...
without `<` or `>` its working too so must be something with the characters.

Comment: as I anderstand entity its the usage of special strings for special characters. but I did use &lt; ... and it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you include actual `"<"` and `">"` characters in your string, like `"<uio>"`, then when you set that as `innerHTML` the browser treats it as an html tag it doesn't recognise and nothing is displayed.

When you use html entities like `"&lt;abc&gt;"` in JS that is inline with your markup the browser first parses it as html and *then* treats it as JS, so what the JS engine has to work with is `"<abc>"`.

You can get around that by doing this in your inline `onclick` handlers:

```
document.getElementById("aaa").innerHTML ='&amp;lt;abc&amp;gt;'
```

...because then by the time the JS engine gets hold of it it will be `"&lt;abc&gt;"`.

Or you can move the JS into a script element and you can use `"&lt;abc&gt;"`.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `innerHTML` to insert `<` and `>`.  Use `textContent`:

`getElementById('aaa').textContent = '<uio>'`